# Must all differentiable $f$ approximately behave linearly like $f'(p)$ in a small neighborhood of p?

Tags: derivatives

I saw that the function $f(x) = {x \over 2} + x^2 \,\text{sin}({1 \over x})$, with $f(0)$ defined as $0$, was used as an example to show that even though a function is differentiable and the derivative is positive at the origin, the function is not monotonically increasing in any neighborhood of the origin.
But the function looks to me close enough to a linear function with slope $1/2$ (this is apparent if one plots it on a computer and zooms into a sufficiently small neighborhood of $0$). I don't mean it's a line in the neighborhood, I know it oscillates, all the way towards 0.

[Figure: almost like a line with 1/2 slope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBanX.png)

**My question**: for a function $f$ differentiable at point $p$, "on average" must $f$ approach a linear function represented by $f'(p)$? It seems plausible, as $f$ is continuous at $p$. If true, please explain; if false, please provide a counter example. Thank you!

**Update**: My confusion was resolved by Ian in the comments. The key is $f(x) - f(p) = f'(p)(x-p) + o(x-p)$.

Comment: In your example you didn't look close enough; $f'$ actually oscillates between $3/2$ and $-1/2$ near $0$. You may have actually looked *too* close, such that in floating point arithmetic $x/2+x^2$ was just $x/2$ again, causing the apparent linear behavior in the figure.

Comment: I know it oscillates, but "on average" (i don't have a more rigorous term) it looks very much like a line. I've just added a screenshot of my plot.

Comment: Well, the question is what you mean by "on average". All that is actually true is $f(x)=f(p)+f'(p)(x-p)+o(x-p)$, so in your example $f(x)=x/2+o(x)$. But something like local monotonicity for example doesn't have to hold.

Comment: At that scale you can't actually see the singularity. It's still there.

Comment: ah, yes, ()=()+′()(−)+(−).
This resolves my confusion. Thank you!
For this reason, $f$'s behaviour is dominated by $f'(p)$ in a sufficiently small neighborhood of $p$.